# Windows 11: set date from text file

Tags: windows-11, date

Per https://stackoverflow.com/a/71911192/4953146: If `current_date.txt` contains the today's date in the format `mm-dd-yyyy`.   This can be used to force the date to `mm-dd-yyyy`:

```
date<currrent_date.txt
```

For some reason Windows 11: the command date /t prepends the day of the week:

- **Wed** 09-19-2023

or

- **DDD** mm-dd-yyyy

How to save the date to a text file without **Wed**?

## UPDATE:

Windows 11 settings at time of original post:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely due to your Windows settings. Try:

- Right-click on the date and time on the taskbar.
- Select “Adjust date and time.”
- Click on “Language and region” at the bottom.
- Scroll down and click on the “Regional format” option.
- Click the “Change formats” button.
- Select a date format from the “Short date” dropdown menu.
- Close the Settings app.

Comment: Thank you!  The date format MM/DD/YYYY removed the DDD (WED).

Comment: @gatorback glad I could help.

Comment: Upvoted.  Thank you